# In a UWP application, how can I tell StreamSocket to use the best TLS protocol among supported by the server?

Tags: c#, sockets, ssl, uwp

StreamSocket.ConnectAsync method accepts values like SocketProtectionLevel.Tls10 or SocketProtectionLevel.Tls12 but not both simultaneously (this enum is not Flags).

With SslStream in .NET Framework, I could specify multiple protocols simultaneously so that the best protocol supported by both parties would be picked up automatically. In fact, I need the app to use TLS 1.2 if supported, or gracefully downgrade to TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.0. Is it possible with UWP applications somehow? I guess I can make multiple connections and if it does not work out with, let's say, TLS 1.2, then reconnect with less secure option. But I'm wondering if this can be done without such overhead.

Comment: According to [SocketProtectionLevel enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.socketprotectionlevel). `SocketProtectionLevel.Tls12` supports the TLS 1.2, TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.0 protocols and all encryption ciphers installed on the system except RC4, other weak ciphers, and the NULL cipher.

Comment: Oh my bad, I didn't notice SocketProtectionLevel.Tls12 supports downgrade (because it's normal .NET framework counterpart behaves differently). Thanks!